# TreeMap - Dynamic ordering elements based on key

Tags: java, collections

I want to use HashMap with ordering of elements. So I choose TreeMap. Below code gives me strange answer, than what I expected

```
public class MapTest {

  public static class Key implements Comparable<Key>{
    private String key;
    private int count;

    public Key(String key, int count){
      this.key = key;
      this.count = count;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
      return key.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
      return key.equals(obj);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Key o) {
      return count - o.count;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Key, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();

    Key c = new Key("c", 4);

    map.put(new Key("a", 6), 1);
    map.put(new Key("b", 8), 1);
    map.put(c, 1);
    map.put(new Key("d", 2), 1);

    for(Map.Entry<Key, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()){
      System.out.println(entry.getKey().key);
    }

    //map.remove(c);
    map.put(c, null);
    c.count = 0;
    map.put(c, 1);

    for(Map.Entry<Key, Integer> entry : map.entrySet()){
      System.out.println(entry.getKey().key);
    }

  }
}
```

If I use `map.remove()` and add element, it is ordered. Otherwise it is always returns the element in order
d c a b

Why above code is not working? put(key, null) should delete the value and if new value is inserted it has to be ordered right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`put(key, null)` does not remove the key from the map. It is still in the map, just mapping to null. You want to `remove(key)`.

Objects used as keys in a Map should be immutable really. You are modifying the key after you put it into the map - but the map has no mechanism to detect that and move the key so as you realized the key ends up at an invalid location.

This can then confuse the `Map` to the point that it doesn't think the key is present in the map at all since it goes to look for it where it should be and it isn't there.